# Unable to change kernel to Python in Azure Data Studio

Tags: python, azure, kernel, azure-data-studio

I've tried to change Azure Data Studio kernel to Python 3 without success (PySpark doesn't work either). The error message is:

```
Failed to change kernel. Kernel SQL will be used. Error was: request to http://localhost:8888/api/sessions?1658840691943 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
```

Meanwhile I can still run notebooks separately without problems. Some source mentioned to check Python to be added to PATH, which I did and saw it was added. If I typed this in cmd:

```
python --version
```

it returned `Python 3.8.8`
And I could also find the location with this cmd entry:

```
where python
```

which gave `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe`

Can you tell what could be a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and found the answer from [Failed to change kernel due to error](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/8322). One of the reasons you are receiving this is due to permissions. Below are the steps that worked out for me.

1. Update your python to the latest version.
2. Run your python environment in the User's folder rather than in the system folder.
3. Make sure the Anaconda is attached to the python in the user directory and not the system directory.